# How to convert a certain program's audio output to mic input

Tags: audio, pulse-audio, audio-recording, audio-streaming, audio-conversion

I have Program A and Program B
-I want Program A's Sound output to be received as a Microphone input
-I want Program B's Sound output to be received as a normal sound output

Is there a way i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/).

There you can set different Audio Devices and reroute them how you like it. You could for example output Spotify on Cable 1 which is also used as an input in Zoom. But your browser for example uses Cable 2 which is used to route the output normally to your headphones.

There is a free version where you get an ad every now and then to test things out, but it's quite handy for specific use cases.

EDIT: It seems they changed their license model to a different one where most of program is free, but you'll have to donate to use more inputs or outputs.